# deploying multiple struts2 applications JBOSS

Tags: deployment, jboss, struts2

I am deploying two struts2 applications as war files to JBOSS4.1 Sp1, i am getting the below error for the second application, while the first application is deployed successfully. 
it works fine for tomcat5.5. Also if i deploy these applications separatly one by one it works.
I have been working since two days to solve it out but no help.

```
    14:41:11,062 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/app1, warUrl=file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17122app1-exp.war/
14:41:14,734 INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
14:41:14,843 INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
14:41:14,875 INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
14:41:14,890 INFO  [DefaultConfiguration] Overriding property struts.i18n.reload - old value: false new value: true
14:41:14,890 INFO  [DefaultConfiguration] Overriding property struts.configuration.xml.reload - old value: false new value: true
14:41:15,468 INFO  [ResponseOverrideFilter] Filter initialized. Response buffering is enabled
```

Stack Trace continues .....

```
14:41:25,046 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/app2, warUrl=file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17123app2-
exp.war/
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.14.184.119:1531:REPPROD has been created with user repapp
14:41:27,093 INFO  [XmlConfigurationProvider] Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
14:41:27,093 ERROR [Engine] StandardContext[/app2]Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17123app2-exp.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-cor
e-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4349)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:823)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:807)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5441)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:289)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:374)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:62)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:40)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:891)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:416)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
        at $Proxy28.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:360)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
        at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:305)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:481)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:204)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:277)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:891)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:416)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:261)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:722)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:413)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:310)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:162)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:423)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1/server/default/tmp/deploy/
tmp17123app2-exp.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:222)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:165)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
        ... 122 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp
1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17122cdf-exp.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1
/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17123app2-exp.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:206)
        ... 125 more
14:41:27,390 INFO  [ResponseOverrideFilter] Filter initialized. Response buffering is enabled
14:41:27,390 ERROR [Context] Error filterStart
14:41:27,390 ERROR [Context] Context startup failed due to previous errors
14:41:27,546 ERROR [WebModule] Starting failed jboss.web.deployment:war=
```

---

.war,id=-611152262
    org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-4.0.1sp1/jboss-4.0.1sp1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp17123app2-exp.war/ deployment failed
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:365)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:92)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:374)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:62)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:40)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:891)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:416)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
            at $Proxy28.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:360)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:122)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:131)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
            at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:305)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:481)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:204)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:277)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:272)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:222)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:891)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:416)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
            at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:261)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:964)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:775)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:722)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:144)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:122)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:131)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:642)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
            at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:413)
            at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:310)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:162)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:423)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    14:41:27,765 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service j

Comment: I have somehow able to fix this issue by adding the jboss-web.xml inside WEB-INF for each war. <jboss-web> <context-root>abc</context-root> <loader-repository> com.xxx.xxx.abc:loader=abc.war <loader-repository-config> java2ParentDelegation=false </loader-repository-config> </loader-repository> </jboss-web> Also i removed all the coomon dependency jar files from WEB-INF/lib and moved to common lib folder of Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

use jboss-web.xml to set java class loading to parent class loader.
below sample will allow users to put the Struts.jar inside the WB-INF/lib

com.SSSS.AAAA.XXXX:archive=your_archive_file.war
            
                java2ParentDelegation=false